# How to publish web service in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

Below url is web service which I hosted: http://monocept.net/vlt/html/AutoComplete.asmx

when I am invoking this service it calls web method GetCompleteList(). This method implementation is defined in AutoComplete.asmx.cs file. When I invoking this service it throws exception as HTTP 404, where as in my local machine service is working fine and able to hit GetCompleteList() Web method.

Comment: Are you specify all required parameters? By the way it seems that your web service doesn't work. Just test it here:http://monocept.net/vlt/html/AutoComplete.asmx?op=GetCompleteList

Comment: Looks like an IIS config issue. What files and folders are there in your virtual directory?

Comment: [IIS Failed Request Tracing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/) to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

The error page is actually dumping out the exception/stack trace in a HTML comment:

```
[HttpException]: The controller for path &#39;/vlt/html/AutoComplete.asmx/GetCompleteList&#39; was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I'm not familiar with MVC, so I really can't give you a solid answer, but researching that exception turns up a few [results](http://techkn0w.wordpress.com/2008/05/15/mvc-controller-routing-error-due-to-incorrect-class-name/).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a controller for this path. It is MVC error. Your service doesn't has a business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that you are excluding the route in your global.asax file?

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
```